# Automapper automatically resolve correct subclass to map to?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, automapper

Given the following source types:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class FirstViewModelImpl : BaseViewModel
{
   public string Prop2 { get; set; } 
}

public class SecondViewModelImpl : BaseViewModel
{
   public string AnotherProp { get; set; }
}
```

And the following destination types

```
public class BaseDto
{
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class FirstDtoImpl : BaseDto
{
   public string Prop2 { get; set; } 
}

public class SecondDtoImpl : BaseViewModel
{
   public string AnotherProp { get; set; }
}
```

With the following mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FirstViewModelImpl,FirstDtoImpl>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SecondViewModelImpl,SecondDtoImpl>();
```

Can I do the following (trivial example) - given that I don't actually know the type of viewmodel until runtime?

```
BaseViewModel myViewModel = GetAViewModelFromSomewhere();
FirstDtoImpl dto = (FirstDtoImpl)Mapper.Map<BaseViewModel,BaseDto>(myViewModel);
```

I am trying this out now anyway!

Comment: Right I've just tried this and it looks like it isn't possible - unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found that if I change the mappings to

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseViewModel,BaseDto>()
        .Include<FirstViewModelImpl,FirstDtoImpl>()
        .Include<SecondViewModelImpl,SecondDtoImpl>();

Mapper.CreateMap<FirstViewModelImpl,FirstDtoImpl>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SecondViewModelImpl,SecondDtoImpl>();
```

Then it works as expected without using the type converter.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that directly, however you can work around it with a TypeConverter.

In the Mappings you will add:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseViewModel, BaseDto>()
    .ConvertUsing<MyTypeConverter>();
```

Then you can create the converter like so:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter<BaseViewModel, BaseDto>
{
    protected override BaseDto ConvertCore(BaseViewModel tViewModel)
    {
        BaseDto vResult = null;
        if(tViewModel is FirstViewModelImpl)
        {
            var vSource = tViewModel as FirstViewModelImpl;
            vResult = Mapper.Map<FirstViewModelImpl,FirstDtoImpl>(vSource);
        }
        else if(tViewModel is SecondViewModelImpl )
        {
            var vSource = tViewModel as SecondViewModelImpl ;
            vResult = Mapper.Map<SecondViewModelImpl ,SecondDtoImpl>(vSource);
        }
        return vResult;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
BaseDto dto= Mapper.Map<BaseViewModel,BaseDto>(myViewModel);
```

and have dto actually be of the type you wanted.

It won't map the Base types to each other though. If that matters I can twist it a bit more.

Comment: Looks promising. Base types don't matter - they're abstract in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an interface instead? Also, there is a non-generic Mapper.Map implimentation that might work better in this case. If you have the mapping set up, you can just pass in the type.

Comment: I'm not sure an interface would help and the non-generic still requires that I know the concrete type.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to pass in typeof(obj) as a parameter? Surely you can resolve the type somehow.

Comment: The only caveat there is that if you pass in two types that you do not have a mapping for, you might be in for some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not correct if you create Mapping for derived types you should when 
map objects specify the derived class also